# Is there a way in a python exception handling, to silently ignore exception/undeclared names without muliplying try/except blocs

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, module

let's say that i have a bunch of instruction which might all raise exceptions and I'd like to simply ignore those that fail.

```
failable_1
failable_2
...
failable_n
```

Ignoring them with the usual exception pattern might quickly become cumbersome:

```
try:
    failable_1
except SomeError:
    pass
try:
    failable_2   
except SomeError:
    pass
...
try:
    failable_n
except SomeError:
    pass
```

This is especially true if it is about declaring a list of possibly non existing symbols:

```
my_list=[optional_1, optional_2, ..., optional_n]
```

(Let's axiomatically assume that somewhere else in the code, there was something like:

```
for (var,val) in zip(optional_variable_names_list, values):
    exec(var+"="+repr(val))
```

)...

Because in this case, you cannot even write the name in the code.

```
my_list=[]
for variable in [optional_1, optional_2, ..., optional_n]: # problem remains here
    try:
        my_list.append(variable)
    except:
        pass
```

wouldn't work. You have to use `eval()`:

```
my_list=[]
for variable in ["optional_1", "optional_2", ..., "optional_n"]:
    try:
        my_list.append(eval(variable))
    except:
        pass
```

So my question is :

Isn't there a way to write something like the `on error next` or `on error ignore` that existed in some old time languages. some kind of :

```
ignore SomeError:
    failable_1
    failable_2
    ...
    failable_n
```

or

```
ignore NameError:
    my_list=[optional_1, optional_2, ..., optional_n]
```

And if not, why would it be a bad idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the pattern somewhat by using a context manager that suppresses an exception by returning `True` if the exception that occurs is one the those specified with the constructor, or otherwise re-raises the exception:

```
class Ignore:
    def __init__(self, *ignored_exceptions):
        self.ignored_exceptions = ignored_exceptions

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if isinstance(exc_value, self.ignored_exceptions):
            return True
        raise
```

so that:

```
with Ignore(NameError, ValueError):
    a = b
```

outputs nothing, while:

```
with Ignore(NameError, ValueError):
    1 / 0
```

raises `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` as expected.

Comment: Not bad. It avoids the need for the `except error: pass`, but you still need to repeat in for every line and you can't use it to only ignore the missing elements in a list declaration.